# what does @protected mean in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, protected

As the dev doc says, `Dart doesn't have the keywords public , protected , and private . If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it's private to its library.` But I found many `@protected` keywords in Flutter framework. What does the `@protected` mean?

```
abstract class InheritedWidget extends ProxyWidget {
  const InheritedWidget({ Key key, Widget child })
    : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  InheritedElement createElement() => InheritedElement(this);

  @protected
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget);
}
```

Comment: [`@protected`](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/protected-constant.html) is an *annotation* (and not a language keyword) provide from `package:meta` and that is used by `dartanalyzer` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's used to provide a hint when members are used outside of subclasses, by the Dart Analyzer.

You can find the issue [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25841).